# javax.jms.JMSException: AMQ219014: Timed out after waiting 30,000 ms for response when sending packet 71

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x, activemq-artemis

I'm using JBoss server with EJB and JMS queue. I'm trying to connect to a remote queue on a different server, but lately it started to disconnect from the queue with following error message:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: AMQ219014: Timed out after waiting 30,000 ms for response when sending packet 71
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0.redhat-00048//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:530)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0.redhat-00048//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:434)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0.redhat-00048//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQSessionContext.sendFullMessage(ActiveMQSessionContext.java:552)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0.redhat-00048//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.sendRegularMessage(ClientProducerImpl.java:296)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0.redhat-00048//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.doSend(ClientProducerImpl.java:268)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0.redhat-00048//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.send(ClientProducerImpl.java:143)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0.redhat-00048//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.send(ClientProducerImpl.java:125)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0.redhat-00048//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.doSendx(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:483)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0.redhat-00048//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:193)
  at deployment.my-logic.jar//com.example.beans.ejb.MyReceiver.distributeToQueue(MyReceiver.java:630)
  at deployment.my-logic.jar//com.example.beans.ejb.MyReceiver.handleMessage(MyReceiver.java:143)
  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.common@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.common@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.common@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:49)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.jpa@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.jpa@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SFSBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SFSBInvocationInterceptor.java:57)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.java:136)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.java:59)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:201)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:392)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:160)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
  at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.common@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
  at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.17.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:633)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:191)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.IdentityInterceptor.processInvocation(IdentityInterceptor.java:49)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
  at deployment.my-logic.jar//com.example.beans.ejb.MyReceiver$$$view2.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:410)
  at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:134)
  at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
  at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:106)
  at deployment.my-logic.jar//com.example.beans.ejb.MyReceiver$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
  at deployment.my-mdb.jar//com.example.beans.ejb.RemoteComponentRequestMDBean.onMessage(RemoteComponentRequestMDBean.java:45)
  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.common@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.common@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.common@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:49)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:201)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:392)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:160)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
  at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.common@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbSuspendInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbSuspendInterceptor.java:57)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentDescription$7$1.processInvocation(MessageDrivenComponentDescription.java:302)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
  at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.17.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:633)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:191)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.IdentityInterceptor.processInvocation(IdentityInterceptor.java:49)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
  at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
  at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
  at deployment.my-mdb.jar//com.example.beans.ejb.RemoteComponentRequestMDBean$$$view8.onMessage(Unknown Source)
  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:139)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.12.GA-redhat-00003//org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:73)
  at deployment.my-mdb.jar//com.example.beans.ejb.RemoteComponentRequestMDBean$$$endpoint5.onMessage(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra@2.16.0.redhat-00048//org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQMessageHandler.onMessage(ActiveMQMessageHandler.java:323)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0.redhat-00048//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1030)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0.redhat-00048//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:49)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0.redhat-00048//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1153)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  at org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)
Caused by: ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219014: Timed out after waiting 30,000 ms for response when sending packet 71]
  ... 168 more
```

Any idea why it is disconnecting from request queue?

This is the `messaging-activemq` configuration in `standalone.xml`:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
    <server name="default">
        <statistics enabled="${wildfly.messaging-activemq.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <jms-queue name="RemoteComponentRequestQueue" entries="java:/jms/RemoteComponentRequestQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="RemoteComponentResponseQueue" entries="java:/jms/RemoteComponentResponseQueue"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

A packet `71` is a "session send" packet from the core protocol used by ActiveMQ Artemis to implement JMS. In other words, it's the packet sent when a JMS client sends a message. This packet requires a response from the remote broker to ensure the broker received the message properly. For some reason the client is not receiving a response from the remote broker. This might happen for the following reasons (in no particular order):

- The remote broker sent a response, but network is too slow or the `callTimeout` (defaults to `30000` millis) is too low.
- The broker is overloaded somehow and wasn't able to respond within the timeout.

In any case this seems more like an environmental or runtime issue rather than a bug or programming mistake. I recommend you inspect your network and your remote broker to ensure they are operating within expected parameters because everything really depends on the conditions in the environment. If the CPU utilization is high (for whatever reason) or if GC activity is high (e.g. because memory is low) the broker may not be able to respond within the timeout. I recommend you monitor the JVM for performance problems and take thread dumps when you see problems. The thread dumps will give you important information about what is happening in the broker. You might also consider increasing the `callTimeout` on your connection to give the broker more time to respond.

Comment: sounds like this exception is more like a symptom, not the root cause. i have checked the remote server and logs of it as well, nothing suspicious, was investigating it during the incident and the network and remote server was available.  could it be the high traffic issue? for example broker could not handle "X" number of messages

Comment: Have already did that, was monitoring CPU utilization and JVM for memory usage, during the incident both of them were healthy, generated thread dump as well. nothing suspicious. i do not know how it will affect the channel if i increase the `callTimeout`

Comment: If CPU utilization and GC activity were both low and thread dumps during the problem don't indicate any kind of problem then that point to the network as the likely culprit.